# Can data ever be too high dimensional for the Lasso?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, lasso, dimensionality-reduction, high-dimensional

I'm trying to implement Lasso on high dimensional textual data.

Format of Data: p ~= 45,000, n~=4,000

When running the Lasso, I get a training score of 0 and the number of features selected as 0. This doesn't make sense to since the Lasso typically identifies a few sparse features.

Now in order to check that I was running the model correctly, I also implemented an SVR and a Ridge Regression. The SVR worked just fine and the Ridge selected 3800 features.

This leads me to think that my data is somehow too high dimensional for the Lasso. Is this correct or is there an alternative explanation for why the Lasso won't select any features and is returning a training score of 0.

Sample of my code:

```
regressor_lasso = Lasso(alpha=1, max_iter=10e5)
regressor_lasso.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_pred = regressor_lasso.predict(X_test)

train_score=regressor_lasso.score(X_train,y_train)
test_score=regressor_lasso.score(X_test,y_test)
coeff_used = np.sum(regressor_lasso.coef_!=0)
```

Output:
- training score: 0.0
- test score:  -0.00012666589088872193
- number of features used:  0

Note that if I replace Lasso with Ridge, coeff_used become ~3800 and training score is no longer zero.

Comment: Could you please say more about how you are choosing your penalization factors for Lasso and ridge? Ridge shouldn't "select" features at all, just provide weighted regression coefficients for all of your 45,000 features. Note that Lasso has worked well on gene-expression data having about 20,000 features and fewer than 1000 cases, so an issue with dimensionality per se with your data seems unlikely.

Comment: Looks like you're using a constant penalty strength (`alpha=1`). If the penalty is set too high, all coefficients will be forced to zero. This is probably what's happening in your case. The typical approach is to select the appropriate penalty strength using cross validation. And, use nested cross validation to estimate the final performance.

Comment: I tried playing around with the alpha and set it to 0.01 but it didn't work initially. Then I set it to 0.00001 and it worked.